# Unable to read file from App folder of Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have created a file in App folder of Google Drive.

**code to write file**

```
OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
try { 
        outputStream.write(text.toString().getBytes()); 
} catch (IOException e1) { 
        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents."); 
}
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("appconfig.txt")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .build();
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(),changeSet,result.getDriveContents())
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

This is successfully writing into App folder. Now I have to read the file that is written.

**Code to read file**

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, driveId);
DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();

System.out.println("result success "+driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess());
```

The status of **driveContentsResult** is false. 
I have seen Google's Demo but couldn't find the solution. Can anybody help me to find whats the error I have done or what is the other way I can try.

Comment: Is there anything noteworthy in our logcat?

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you provided some more info, but here are a few things you could try:

1. Checkout https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInAppFolderActivity.java
2. Check the error message in the result: driveContentsResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage()
3. Look for any relevant log outputs in the logcat